# Adding the WHERE Statement in the SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql

Hi guys after the help in another post I managed to get the following Update SQL statement to work however I wish to add a WHERE.

So I have:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Schedule SET Schd_Avaliable = '" + "No" + "'", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And I want to add a Where which looks for the Schd_ID in the table and a schdid which is from a session however with all the punctuation im unsure where to put it.

This is the Where I made:

```
WHERE Schd_ID = schdid
```

just unsure where to put that exactly in the line below without it throwing an error:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Schedule SET Schd_Avaliable = '" + "No" + "'", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Mark

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Schedule SET Schd_Avaliable = '" + "No" + "' WHERE Schd_ID ='" + schdid + "'", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
 string sql = "UPDATE Schedule SET Schd_Avaliable = 'No' WHERE Schd_ID = @schdid";
 cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@schdid", int.Parse(Session["SchdID"].ToString()));
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Modify as needed for your session, and column names.

Comment: I'd even put the 'No' into a parameter personally. I find it easier to read and it is just good practice in ASP to stop someone creating a SQL injection problem for you down the track.

Comment: Hiya Yeh I was informed about SQL injection before but im only doing an intro to asp at uni so at the moment as long as the principles work its ok but thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Mark: If you doing "an intro to asp at uni" then you should be teaching best practice: so we don't have to beat such nonsense out of graduates...

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended to use Sql Parameters in this situation.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE Schedule
                          SET Schd_Avaliable = @ScheduleAvailable
                        WHERE Schd_ID = @ScheduleID", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ScheduleAvailable", "No") );
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ScheduleID", schdid.ToString()));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
"UPDATE Schedule SET Schd_Avaliable = '" + "No" + "'" + "WHERE Schd_ID = '" + schdid + '"
```

Comment: What if `schid` contains value `1 OR 1=1; DROP TABLE Schedule; SELECT * FROM SalaryEmployee`?

Comment: campbell: The question didn't ask about parameterized queries. @GoG answered the question asked. It would have been better to add some info about parameters afterward, however.

Comment: No, the question didn't. Part of the process is learning good habits. I didn't even both mentioning stored procs either. Same with the unneeded readability problem with unnecessary concatenation of the 'no'. To be clear, that's not my downvote on this answer.

Comment: @p.campbell sure, it is no a good approach because there can be SQL injections etc. but this is very basic question about where to add the "WHERE" clause in a SQL statement!!! so, if someone is not sure where "WHERE" should be putted then how to explain about parameters?!

Comment: However, your answer is great, but for more skilled developer... so i'll give a vote up :)